# Reversing bootstrap carousel doesn't work on the first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to reverse the direction of the bootstrap carousel, and I found the code below which works except on the first item. The first item goes from right to left, and the others from left to right (I want that).

Anybody knows what is the problem please ?

Here is the javascript code I found:

```
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.next = function () {
  if (this.sliding)
    return;
  return this.slide('prev');
};

$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.prev = function () {
  if (this.sliding)
    return;
  return this.slide('next');
};
```

Comment: It works good for me. https://codepen.io/makshh/pen/dRjdbg?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I used your HTML and it worked ! Problem solved :)